# Would hotels/motels/hostels serve a purpose when everyone has a magic bedroom they can teleport to?

Tags: magic, society, economy, fantasy-races, sleep

In my modern fantasy novel, there is a species of people called the Torus. The Torus are blue-skinned humanoids who suffer from dyslexia and dyscalculia. This makes it difficult for them to perform certain white-collar jobs or be educated. That said, the Torus have a lot of free time thanks to their superpower. Each Torus is able to access their own private universe. They are effectively a species that don't need equipment for sleep. Here are the rules:

- Each Torus can teleport to their private pocket universe by performing a series of gestures that take 5 seconds.
- A torus can take up to one person or animal with them, but said organism must touch the Torus while they're gesturing and they must mentally consent to be teleported.
- This private pocket universe looks and feels like the inhabitants are above the clouds. There are soft, solid, and fluffy clouds below them (you cannot fall down) and breathable outer space above them.
- The torus can increase the light and dark levels of their universe. They can also change the ambient sounds or make it completely silent.
- The pocket universe seemingly stretches on forever, but it is actually about the size of Barbados (the universe wraps around).
- There is no way to access another Torus pocket universe (outside of being brought along). There is also no way to contact a Torus while they're in their pocket universe.
- Time passes by much slower within the pocket universe. One minute in the pocket universe equals 1 second in real life.
- Organisms within the pocket universe also age 60x slower. Their metabolism also slows down.
- No possessions beyond clothing and pocket contents can be taken to a pocket universe. Anything left behind in a pocket universe is permanently gone.
- When a Torus performs the gesture to leave the pocket universe, they are exactly where they were last time (or as close as possible depending on space).
- When a Torus leaves their pocket universe, their passenger automatically comes with them as well.
- If the Torus was on a vehicle when they left, they will teleport back to the vehicle (if possible).

So effectively, the Torus never needs beds, toilets, or intimate quarters. They are also technically active for 99% of their life as opposed to around 67%. In an overwhelmingly mdoern Torus society, would there be any need for temporary lodging like a hotel or a hostel considering Torus can always sleep in their universes? A Torus can teleport and sleep in their pocket universe at anytime. With no need for beds, what other purpose would hotels or hostels serve? Baggage storage can be handled by rental companies (e.g. Uhaul). Entertainment can be handled by bars, theaters, and similar establishments. Food can be handled by restaurants. Those are generally what a hotel provides. I'm pretty sure brothels and restrooms are also obsoleted by this power, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: what does a pocket universe contain? can the tori generate anything in their universe, or would they have to bring things into their universe manually? this is a critical element of whether hotels are viable or not.

Comment: "Time passes by much slower within the pocket universe. One minute in the pocket universe equals 1 second in real life" - If you meant that time flows more slowly inside the pocket universe, it must be the other way round.

Comment: Why the tag [[tag:crime]]?

Comment: Also, I think the question about *hotels* is jumping the gun a bit. What about an ordinary family of 3+? A couple can "live together" at either one's place but without any pets. And they can't have their partner and a kid over at the same time. They can't have 2+ guests of any sort - be it family, friends, people to play board games with (or whatever the equivalent is). Sure, there are bars and other establishments for that, but does do the Torians really just go "see you next morning" pop out of existence then pop back in together all the time?

Comment: Given the diversity of designs for hostels/motels/hotels on earth what makes you think that this question has a sufficiently limited range of valid answers to be an appropriate question for this site?

Comment: Changing just the title does nothing to meaningfully shift what your question is asking about. Not only does it not resolve the issues your post has it creates confusion about what you're actually asking. Please remember that edits should not invalidate existing answers. Finally it's your world you get to decide if hotels exist in it or not and how they are used. If you choose for a hotel to exist in your world than it can usually be assumed that it has some purpose for being, unless you permit things in your world to exist without reason, which renders this question moot.

Comment: Just FYI as a scientist with 3 degrees and both dyslexia and dyscalculia its not that much of a problem with getting educated.  It just means slightly more awareness and small amount of extra work.

Comment: VTC. You tell us a lot about the pocket universe itself, yet say nothing about the nature of travel among the Torus. From the long historical perspective, people on Earth have demonstrated a desire if not an absolute need for some kind of place of rest when travelling. Not just a bedroom, but a place to eat, a place to get boinked, a place to exchange news, a place to stable pack animals and all of that within the relative safety of numbers and a strong or defensible location. Sure a torus can kip in his own private universe, but what about all the pack animals, baggage and so forth (cont)

Comment: (cont) that he's got with him? They don't have their own universe to nip into. You've placed a somewhat odd restriction on what can be taken inside. You've placed another odd restriction on what can be left behind. Basically, I'd like you think backwards in time. Forget about UHaul --- think about the toruses social past before all those modern things. That's where the answer to your question lies. And you're going to have to tell us more about that ancient past before we can hope to provide a good answer! Also, have you considered: *yes, they need hotels for the tourists* as a viable option?

Comment: I don't understand why this obviates the need for beds and toilets. People don't sleep anyplace it's soft and dark, nor do they poop anywhere no one's looking. I could walk into the woods at night, lie on some moss, and crap in a hole - that doesn't mean I would not prefer to sleep in a bed or use a toilet.

Comment: I think this is potentially answerable. But first you need to clarify what proportion of the population are Torus, and are the rest just normal humans?

Comment: A negative to this capability: Police enter a residence to find several hungry children, dirty, feces on the floor, and the place a mess. "Mommy and daddy went into their private universe last week and we haven't had food since then." This happens today with drugs, alcohol, and gambling.

Answer (score 4):

Many hotels are "destination spots." They are not just places to sleep. They include health spas, convention centers, casinos, entertainment, and amusement parks. One goes to those hotels to partake of all the other activities.

People can get bored in their own private universe and will want to experience other designed places. Specially designed bedrooms attract a lot of visitors.

It is hard to have an orgy when limited to only two people in a space. Part of the thrill is watching other people have fun.

Comment: Upvoted purely for the Orgy comment :D

Answer (score 4):

***Assumption:** Your rules state that Torus in their pocket universes age at 1/60th the rate and have only 1/60th the metabolism. This was an effort to make use of the pocket universes free without actually saying the word "magic." But unless you declare it to be "alternative physics and biology" (aka "magic"), that means they need 60X the sleep and 60X the effort to pick up a pencil (picking up a 1# object would feel like picking up a 60# object). I'm simplifying as metabolism is more complex than that. You need your metabolism to rejuvenate the body during sleep and to do anything at "normal" speeds. So it's a rational simplification that makes the point. I'm ignoring the metabolism and aging rules (I'm giving into the need for magic) as I don't think the pocket universe is good for anything but dry goods storage otherwise.*

---

Your pocket universe rules are suitably limiting, so there are *very human* reasons why temporary lodging is necessary.

- As mentioned earlier in comments: if two parents want to rest with one or more under-age children (like babies...) they're stuck with temporary lodging.
- And it all gets worse with pets, also from a comment.
- Anyone traveling with more than the clothes on their back and the proverbial lint in their pockets would need temporary lodging. Heaven help someone traveling with a cart/car who is out of contact in their pocket universe while the stable/garage is burning down!

And communication might be the biggest reason to use temporary housing — you're in a situation (a multi-family vacation, for instance) where the need to be *available* for something during the night would rationalize the need for hotels/motels/hostels.

Technology is an important question, too! If the Torus live in a world filled with electricity, that would be something they wouldn't have (ignoring batteries...) in their pocket universes. They certainly wouldn't have access to electromagnetic transmissions, so no television, cellphones, or internet for you! On the other hand, there's a benefit with battery-powered tools in that you could get a lot of work done compared to what you could do in the normal universe.

**What's your culture like?**

Your culture would have developed around your rules. We're looking at this as if human rules apply. In your culture, a prohibition/taboo against having more underage children than there are parents to tend them might develop. This harks back to the days of *I Love Lucy* where she and Desi slept "together" in separate beds.

Your culture might also send juveniles off to "training camp" in their universes! I doubt you could get the adults involved as they'd loose to much of their lives, but if you could trust the juveniles to actually study on their own, they would learn and mature very quickly, spending a month in their pocket universe for every 12 hours of normal time. That's a serious advantage — so long as you don't need teachers!

But that problem with hiring teachers is a pretty strong argument for needing temporary lodging. Who wants to lose so much of their life to a pocket universe? Yes, you could go get eight quick hours of sleep in just eight minutes of normal time... but you're back just in time for everyone else to go to bed and nothing to do but skulk through the night wondering whether or not you can rob your neighbors!

So, depending on how you develop the social structure of the Torus, the pocket universe may have little real value other than to store valuables — but only valuables that don't age quickly! It's the size of Barbados, but you don't mention if the pocket universe used by someone today is the very same pocket universe used by them tomorrow. If it is, then your society would very likely have temporary and permanent housing... what they wouldn't have are safes, strong boxes, or racks of keys... at least not on the planet itself!

**Conclusion**

I'm going with yes. I can rationalize why the Torus would need temporary lodging.

Comment: Great answer, but you got the time ratios confused. If you spend one minute in the pocket universe, only one second passed in real life. This is why the pocket universe is great for sleeping and pooping and a few other tasks. A torus can effectively do their business and be back in mere minutes or even seconds. That is why there is a sleep tag and I said Torus have a lot more free time.

Comment: @Rhymehouse Dang nabit. You're right! I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A torus goes on a vacation and takes a friend with him. His friend is not a torus, so he/she does not have his/her own space. His friend is a human, a pet, an alien, and so on... Sure, the torus can take his friend with him into the pocket universe, but that friend still needs a shower, a toilet, and so on. On the other hand, the friend books a hotel room just for him/herself. He/she does not have to pay the extra for his torus friend, because that friend goes to sleep elsewhere in the "universe". It is in the morning that the torus leaves his pocket universe and rejoins his friend who is touring new destinations.

Answer (score 2):

Things that a Hotel provides instead of just Sleeping:

- Local Knowledge.

Think the Concierge - I'm a stranger in a strange place and I want to know where is good to eat, where is good to party, which ladies of the night are reputable etc. etc. A good hotel Concierge is able to impart a significant amount of local knowledge in order to make my stay in the *area* pleasant. Now, granted, this could be done by an information Kiosk but - I'll get to that in a mo.

- Rest and Relaxation.

Most good hotels will include various facilities - a Gym, Pool maybe a Spa etc. etc. Having a single place where all of these types of facilities are would make sense. If you've spent all day in a foreign place looking at things, going places etc. etc. you are going to be tired. Perhaps not 'Go to sleep' tired, but definitely 'Need to relax' tired - and so a nice Pool or Spa can go a long way to that end. Now, Granted this could be done at a leisure centre but - I'll get to that in a mo.

- Work and Weddings.

Most good hotels will include a conference room/area or just a big room that can be used for things like Weddings or Receptions or similar. Things that by their nature would be difficult for the Torus to do independently because they are en-masse and collaborative in nature. A Hotel would be great for this. Now, Granted this could be a community hall but - I'll get to that in a mo.

- Food and Drink.

The Restaurant and the Bar. A good Hotel will have a nice restaurant and I've had a few pretty damn good meals at a Hotel. I've also been away on business and enjoyed an alcoholic beverage or two on the company dime at a nice Hotel Bar.
Now, Granted this could be done at a Restaurant/Bar - but I'll get to that in a mo.

So - the observant of you will note a repeating motif - that all of the ancillary and additional functions of a Hotel can and are performed by other buildings/places/businesses - the value, however, is having them all in a single place easily accessible to a traveler.

Combining all these features and services into one place still makes sense - and therefore having a Hotel will still make sense.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, there are some open questions about family life, and (if they interact with humans) whether the Torus participate in social situations involving sleep, e.g. camping trips, sleepovers, orgies etc.  But I assume the thrust of the question is “would hotels exist if people didn’t need to sleep”.

One obvious point is that the bed is only half of what hotels provide; do the Torus need bathrooms?  If so, they might want something like the public baths common in many countries, but that’s quite different to hotels.

Still, I think there would be very little economic room for hotels if people didn’t need a private space to sleep every single day.   Most hotels are basically warehouses for sleep, not attractions in their own right. And even in a world where people need hotels for survival, it’s a notoriously difficult business.

There would be a space for resorts, but they’d be more like theme parks.  Or you might have an equivalent of bed-and-breakfasts, but it would be more like having a local guide who lets you hang out in their house – they wouldn’t set aside bedrooms and do all the associated work if they didn’t have to.

The fact that the Torus are effectively awake 24/7 would have much wider-ranging implications, of course, especially if they share the world with regular humans.